# Given the sides of a polygon, determine if it is convex or concave

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, polygons

We are given the lengths of all sides of a polygon. We need to determine if the given polygon is convex or concave. How can this be done? What is the propery applied to determine this?

Comment: [It can't be done](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0vSd9.png).

Comment: ohkk.. thanx a lot . In case if we are given some straight lines (with length of each of them) , how can we determine if convex polygon formation is possible or not using each of those lines?

Comment: @user249117 If it's possible to form a polygon from given line segments, then it's possible to form a convex one from these.

Comment: @Wojowu thanks a lot :)

Comment: What is a "concave polygon", by the way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summary of comments: [Lucian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1562897/given-the-sides-of-a-polygon-determine-if-it-is-convex-or-concave#comment3182287_1562897) gave an example of two polygons with the same sidelengths, only one of which is convex.

[image: polygons]

[Wojowu](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1562897/given-the-sides-of-a-polygon-determine-if-it-is-convex-or-concave#comment3182328_1562897) added that "If it's possible to form a polygon from given line segments, then it's possible to form a convex one from these."

Additional remark: if you know the coordinates $V_j$ of vertices, then the signs of scalar cross-products of vectors $V_jV_{j+1}$ can be used to determine convexity. I.e., the determinants such as 
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
V_2^x-V_1^x & V_3^x-V_2^x \\
V_2^y-V_1^y & V_3^y-V_2^y
\end{vmatrix}
$$
must be all $\ge 0$, or all $\le 0$. (Including one with $V_n$ and $V_1$ to close the loop.)